# Terminal doesn't wait for user prompts

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, mate

I have a strange issue with Mate terminal on my Ubuntu 14. Whenever I am prompted for something, the terminal continues as if I pressed Enter without typing anything. This makes working with terminal impossible, as I can't provide nearly any user input.

- I can't run any command as superuser, because when I'm prompted for password, the question pops up and immediately the command exits.
- I can't connect to known ssh server, because I get prompted for password three times and never input anything.
- I can't connect to unknown ssh server, because when the client asks to verify unknown host (yes/no), the answer is "Enter" (probably) and the command exits.

The last is the weirdest one, as the error message is displayed on the same line as the prompt

```
user@virtualbox:~$ ssh unknown.server
The authenticity of host 'unknown.server (IP)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is .....
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? Host key verification failed.
user@virtualbox:~$
```

I use Kubuntu 17 on my main system and I have never had such issues. I am not calling the commands with "accept all" option, such as `-Y`. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Look contents of `~/.bashrc` file, if is there any weird command there. Does this error happens in a tty-session?

Comment: Thank you, I have already found the cause. Bashrc is default with some additional `source` commands. Other tty sessions now work.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried switching terminals and found out that the problem is caused by `roscore` command being run in another terminal. Once roscore was terminated, prompts started to work.

Comment: Great! You saved your day!

Comment: Please accept your answer by clicking the tick next to it.

Comment: Thank you, I certainly will, however, own answers can't be accepted until 2 days after being posted

Comment: Would be nice to run some deeper investigation to understand what's going on behind the scenes. Is it broken for everyone who execute `roscore` in another terminal emulator tab/window/app? Is only `mate-terminal` broken or other terminal emulators as well? How come `roscore` is able to break all other terminals? I'd totally not be happy or willing to accept if in order to run an app I wish to run, I wouldn't be able to use terminal emulators any more. Are developers of `roscore` aware of the issue?